Stream video from an URL using Spring boot as a proxy
I need to make an endpoint that streams video. The video to stream is from Home Assistant cameras, which uses HLS format.
I've tried different techniques but I'm not able to see the video streaming in a browser natively or even using an HTML player. I see the data is being streamed, I'm just not sure if it's the correct data.
This is what I have so far:

@Service

@Override
public StreamingResponseBody streamVideo(String cameraId) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://localhost:8123/api/camera_proxy_stream/camera.back_patio_sub?token=c88e0f18d35004dd9051e477d3c4125894d2fc5db7b820450892d236cd65a603";

    log.info("Streaming from: {}", url);
    return outputStream -> {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    try (InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent()) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    };
}


@RestController

@GetMapping(value = "/stream/{cameraId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamVideo(@PathVariable String cameraId) throws Exception {
    
    try {
        StreamingResponseBody stream = cameraLiveService.streamVideo(cameraId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .header(CONTENT_LENGTH, DEFAULT_CONTENT_LENGHT)
                .header(PRAGMA, NO_CACHE)
                .header(CACHE_CONTROL, NO_CACHE)
                .body(stream);
    } catch (AsyncRequestTimeoutException ex) {
        //Configurable value for timeout in application.properties:spring.mvc.async.request-timeout
        log.error("Timeout streaming video from camera: {}", cameraId, ex);
        throw new StreamRequestTimeoutException("Timeout streaming video from camera: " + cameraId, ex);
    } 
}

If I paste the Home Assistant URL in the browser it starts playing without any issues, but when I try to proxy it I can't make it happen.
The proxy is needed for security reasons, to use a stored Home Assistant Long Lived Token but that's the only reason.
I've also tried with RestTemplate but seems like the data is not being transmitted, the CloseableHttpClient is what I've see to actually do something.
Also, no exceptions seems to be thrown when "streaming" the data.
What am I missing here?

I found a solution for this. Since I was able to see bytes coming I knew the issue was on the response itself so I decided to keep the Headers from the Home Assistant (orignal feed) and removed the ones I was setting.
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();

//Keep the headers from the response.
for (Header header : headers) {
   response.setHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
}

